# Dealing with cables on the walls

Tags: cable-management

Whats the best way to hide or rather manage cables? Like for instance, I had setup some surveillance cameras which are wired.

Comment: Are there any mains power cords included in this cabling?

Comment: What type of walls (brick, drywall, plaster, etc.)? How long are the cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Surface-mounted raceways** are the typical approach, other than opening up the walls and putting the cables in them (or putting conduit in them so you can replace cables as they become obsolete.)

Common trade names for “raceway” (or conduit) include “Panduit” and “Wiremold”.

Or for the super industrial look, just attach conduit to the surface of the wall...